# Using Commandbar from Office UI Fabric React v6.47.2 for SP Starter Kit

Tags: development, spfx, spfx-extensions

I am currently refactoring some parts of the [SP-Starter kit](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-starter-kit) so as part of this, I am creating new solutions and manually adding code from the starter kit over to my solutions.

Since I am creating new solutions, I need to install dependencies individually as I find them. One of the dependencies from the SP Starter kit (specifically office-ui-fabric-react/lib/CommandBar) has been reworked quite a bit in V6. A bunch of things have been deprecated and tweaked.

One of the changes is around adding Items to the Commandbar in the fabric. Has anyone come across this error when adding items to the commandbar in v6.47:

> Error - typescript - src/common/myLinks/MyLinksDialog.tsx(170,31): error TS2322: Type '{ items: ({ key: string; text: string; onClick: () => Promise; } | { key: string; text: str...' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & ICommandBarProps'.

Please let me know if any more information is needed.
Thanks

Comment: I am also receiving this error, can you tell me where to find the fix? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I managed to resolve this issue.

Since the Commandbar was updated in the ui-fabric-react library, one of the items in the constructors had changed. I used the examples from the UI-fabric documentation which shows how to instantiate the command-bar items and changed my declaration.

The build does not get this error anymore (it gets a different error now - I am working on the new error now).